# How use sub and superscript in Mathematica text, eg: chemical formulas?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is not quite a programming question, but it's about a programming environment, so hopefully not too out of place.  I need to be able to write chemical formulas in Mathematica text (this is specifically about text, not input/code).  Something like: **H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup>**.  But Mathematica can't seem to do this.  If you use the normal sub/superscript functions, or hit Cntl-_ or Cntl-6, it puts you in "math mode" even when you are in text, and so the letters become italic, and it puts a space between the 3 and the O.  Like this: ***H*<sub>3</sub> *O*<sup>+</sup>**.  Ugly, especially with longer chemicals.

Other things in Mathematica work like normal word processors -- you can style fonts as italic, bold, big, small, colored -- but the subscript and superscript functions common in word processors seems to be missing.

Am I missing something?  I hope so...

thanks,
Rob

Comment: You might have more luck with this question at superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a trick similar to that used in LaTeX for printing subscripts on the left. That is place the subscript on an object with no width.

To enter math mode type Cntl-( and to exit type Cntl-) .

Attach the sub and superscripts to ⋮null⋮ or ⋮ ⋮ or ⋮- ⋮ (where ⋮ = escape)

Here's how it displays - compared to some expressions in mathmode:
[image: the chemical formula for hydronium is HSubscript[[Null], 3]O[Null]^+]

I've placed the Cell Expression in a [gist](http://gist.github.com/611053) for you.

Answer (score 4):

In ChemData, Mathematica uses contructs like

```
 Style[
     Row[
          {Subscript["H",3],Superscript["O","+"]}
        ],
          Rule[ScriptBaselineShifts,{0.5`,0.75`}]
      ]
```

Example:

[image]

HTH!